# Breadcrumb link customize

Tags: sxa

We are using Sitecore SXA and adding breadcrumb component from the toolbox.
It is working fine , however, we need to remove Home link from the breadcrumb:

For example :

```
Home > Test > Test Data
```

In the above example , we would like to exclude Home link and the output would be like this :

```
Test > Test Data
```

I have tried breadcrumb default setting property `"Start page"`  but when we select any page, it shows that page on the breadcrumb option on the page only, it is not getting the proper navigation path.

[image]

My question here is , is there any way to remove `Home` link in breadcrumb?

Answer (score 2):

On each page level under the Navigation section, there will be a checklist field `Check to hide navigation filters`. This field will give you multiple checkboxes to hide the page from different navigation. -

[image]

You need to check the `Breadcrumb Navigation` from this list and after that need to configure your control to set the `Navigation Filter` to `Breadcrumb Navigation` -

[image]

Please ignore the different UI in the screenshot as I am using a browser plugin.

Comment: Where can we check `Check to hide navigation filters` this option  as I am not able to find it ?

Comment: You can find it under the Navigation section of your home and other pages.